# django-cms: reverse url to an/another apphook - multilingual

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls, django-cms

I have two apphooks (on a multilingual page) and need create one url with url reverse to the other apphook, but it gives me a

> NoReverseMatch
>   Error.

**Any ideas how to fix it?**

---

Django CMS version: 2.4.3

Django version 1.5.5

---

These are my apphook files of one (working) apphook, the other one is quite similar. 
cms_app.py:

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ProjectsAppHook(CMSApp):
    name = _("Projects")
    urls = ["projects.urls"]

apphook_pool.register(ProjectsAppHook)
```

views.py:

```
def projectsCategoryOverview(request):
    projectCategories=ProjectCategory.objects.all().order_by('name').select_related()
    #return render(request,'projectCategoryOverview.html', {'projectcategories': projectCategories})
    return render_to_response('projectCategoryOverview.html',
                    {'projectcategories': projectCategories},
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I'v found the problem.

I haven't created the page to which it should link to in the language the source page was displayed.